# How to split a pandas dataframe (Date,Value) in two single arrays X=Date and y=Value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if it was possible to split a dataframe that actually is like this (Date is value's index so I have only one column, right?)

```
df_new = df['Value']

Date          Value
2014-01-02    2.713178
2014-01-03    2.751270
2014-01-06    2.758195
2014-01-07    2.792825
2014-01-08    2.806676
2014-01-09    2.787630
2014-01-10    2.830916
```

into two single arrays Date and Value, possibly translating the Date one into ordinals so that I could use Date as "X" and Value as "Y"

How could I do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First column is called `index`, for converting to `numpy array` use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
X = df.index.values
print (X)
['2014-01-02T00:00:00.000000000' '2014-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2014-01-06T00:00:00.000000000' '2014-01-07T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2014-01-08T00:00:00.000000000' '2014-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2014-01-10T00:00:00.000000000']
```

For ordinals add `map`:

```
X = df.index.map(lambda x: x.toordinal()).values
print (X)
[735235 735236 735239 735240 735241 735242 735243]

Y = df['Value'].values
print (Y)
[ 2.713178  2.75127   2.758195  2.792825  2.806676  2.78763   2.830916]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with X = df.index.map(lambda x: x.toordinal()) I wasn't getting an array but a int64Index pandas datatype, adding .values solved it!